# Mysql query for finding followers and following

Tags: mysql, sql

Here are the two tables:

```
1.user
user_id  |  full_name   | username
1              A             A_1
2              B             B_2
3              C             C_3
4              D             D_4
5              E             E_5

2.user_follower
user_id  |  follower_id  |  follow_dtm
2              4            2018-10-09 10:10:10
2              3            2018-01-09 11:10:10
1              5            2018-11-09 07:10:10
4              2            2018-10-09 06:10:10
4              5            2018-10-09 00:10:10
```

Find follower of user: 2
Output should be:

```
user_id: 4  fullname: D username: D_4  f_total_flwr: 2 (num of flwr of id-4)  following: yes
user_id: 3  fullname: C username: C_3  f_total_flwr: 0 (num of flwr of id-3)  following: no
```

I need a mysql query to find all the followers of a particular user  with detail information of the followers from `user` table and  need to know the number of followers each follower has and i also need to if the the particular user also following the follower. Here's what I have tried:

```
SELECT u.user_id 
     , u.full_name
     , u.username
     , COUNT(DISTINCT uf.follower_id) f_total_flwr
     , case when b.user_id is null then 'no' else 'yes' end following 
  FROM user_follower
  JOIN user u 
    ON user_follower.follower_id = u.user_id
  LEFT 
  JOIN user_follower uf 
    ON u.user_id = uf.user_id
  LEFT 
  JOIN user_follower b 
    ON b.user_id = user_follower.follower_id 
   and b.user_id = u.user_id 
 WHERE user_follower.user_id=2 
 GROUP 
    BY u.user_id 
 ORDER 
    BY uf.follow_dtm DESC 
 LIMIT 30
```

I know I'm getting close ;). The problem is, I'm getting `following` with a `yes` value even though the user is not following back.Here is another weird thing - `not all` but `some of them` showing `yes` which should be `no` .Thanks!

Comment: can you please add some sample data and your expected output in table format?

Comment: *But something is wrong* can you describe it more detailed?

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the columns you select, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Comment: Described the problem @Jens .

Comment: @Sharecorn Please add sample data and expected result

Comment: And format the query properly.

Comment: Sample data and expected output are added @Jens

Comment: I have edited the question with more details. Check out @jarlh

Comment: have you tried the answer @Sharecorn ?

Comment: I think it's good practice to assign an alias to EVERY instance of a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select u2.*,b.fcount, case when uf3.user_id is null then 'no' else 'yes' end as connected from user u2 inner join
(
select u.user_id,count(distinct(uf2.follower_id)) fcount
from user u 
inner join user_follower uf1 on u.user_id=uf1.follower_id and uf1.user_id=1
left join user_follower uf2 on uf2.user_id=uf1.follower_id
group by u.user_id
) b on u2.user_id=b.user_id
left join user_follower uf3 on u2.user_id=uf3.user_id and uf3.follower_id=1
```

I tried it using the following data sets:

USER

1,a,abcd

2,b,bcde

3,c,cdef

user_follower

1,2,10

1,3,11

2,3,10

3,1,13

And got the expected result:

2,b,bcde,1,no

3,c,cdef,1,yes

Comment: Everything is ok except not getting the rows where user is not followed back @Gautham M

Comment: `inner join user_follower uf2 on uf2.user_id=uf1.follower_id ` replaced with `left join user_follower uf2 on uf2.user_id=uf1.follower_id` and it worked .

Comment: yupp `inner join` at that place didn't return the users who had 0 followers.